Бесконечное выполнение команды npx prisma migrate dev
Я создал в Supabase новую таблицу, и добавил ее в свой .env файл. При попытке выполнения команды npx prisma migrate dev просто происходит бесконечное выполнение и ничего не происходит. Может сталкивался кто с этим?
